# A matrix as the product of other two matrices.

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Assume $A$ be matrix of order $m×n$. Can we write the $A$ as product of two other matrices say, $P$ $(m×l)$ and $B$ $(l×n)$.

That is

$$A=PB$$
Is this possible for every matrices?

Comment: Take any invertible matrix $X\neq I$ and let $P=AX$ and $B=X^{-1}$.

Comment: This only depends on the rank of $A$. If it is $l$ or less, then it is possible

Comment: Are you fixing $l$ or just looking for the existence of such a dimension $l$? If you allow any $l$ then the comment of @Vercassivelaunos gives you a possibility. Otherwise you must require that $l\geq\mathrm{rank}(A)$...

Comment: @Exodd it is the other way round.. you need the rank of $A$ to be no more than $l$.